# Can't align 6 div's over total width

Tags: css

I made this html

```
<body style="margin:0px">

<div class="statbar">
<div class="stat">sd</div>
<div class="stat">sd</div>
<div class="stat">sd</div>
<div class="stat">sd</div>
<div class="stat">sd</div>
<div class="stat">sd</div>

</div>
</body>
```

Since the page is displayed on different resolutions, I use percentages. I want the space between all the div's to be te same.

So I have 6 div's, so that is 7 spacings between them.

100%-7% (1% for each spacing) = 93%.
93%/6 = 15.5% per div.

So, I use this CSS:

```
.stat{
background-color: #0072C6;
width: 15.5%; 
height: 50px;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
margin-left: 1%;
margin-right: 0px;
display:inline-block;
padding:0px;
border:0px;

}

.statbar{
display:inline-block;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
width:100%;
}
```

The total should be 99% of the total 100% width, but still it does not fit. Why?

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score 4):

Your percentages are fine, but since you changed the display to inline-block, the elements are now sensitive to white space in your code. Try this to fix it:

```
<div class="statbar"><div class="stat">sd</div><div class="stat">sd</div><div class="stat">sd</div><div class="stat">sd</div><div class="stat">sd</div><div class="stat">sd</div></div>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/tArfS/)**

An alternative way to remove the white space is to use HTML comments like:

```
<div class="statbar">
    <div class="stat">sd</div><!--
    --><div class="stat">sd</div><!--
    --><div class="stat">sd</div><!--
    --><div class="stat">sd</div><!--
    --><div class="stat">sd</div><!--
    --><div class="stat">sd</div>
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/bbTV2/)**

One other technique to deal with the space is to set the font size on the parent element to zero, and then whatever non-zero size you prefer on the child.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/bTykm/)**

And finally, you could float the stat divs:

```
.stat {
    background-color: #0072C6;
    width: 15.5%;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right: 0px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0px;
    border:0px;
    float:left;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/A54uD/)**

Answer (score 0):

I've removed the unnecessary code from the CSS style. here is [working demo](http://jsbin.com/duponuja/2/edit).

```css
.stat {
  background-color: #0072C6;
  width: 15.5%; 
  height: 50px;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:0 auto;
  margin:0 auto
}

.statbar {
  width:100%;
}
```